# ArchLinux-SSH-First time boot

Tags: archlinux, ssh

I am trying to use my RPI without a keyboard (hasn't arrived yet). I have installed ArchLinux on the SD card and it's booting fine. Using OS X I am trying to connect to the RPI by connecting it directly to my laptop via ethernet (no router available).

The RPI appears on ifconfig at en0 with inet 169.254.233.8. 
Then, in Terminal I run

```
ssh alarmpi@169.254.233.8
```

and get

```
ssh: connect to host 169.254.233.8 port 22: Connection refused
```

although SSH is said to be enabled by default on arch Linux. Am I doing something wrong, or doesn't it just work this way?

Comment: How are the two devices connected?

Comment: Directly via Ethernet.

Comment: Is your macintosh on the same subnet as the raspberry pi? Is 169.254.233. the first 3 octates of your host IP? I am not sure if this will matter.

Comment: Can you `ping` the Pi OK?

Comment: I believe there is something wrong with the connection. Im probably using wrong IP for RPI and most likely there is not IP for it.. I tried to ping the broadcast IP for the bridge0 found in ifconfig but only 1 IP is returned. Also en1 is empty.

Comment: When you say directly via Ethernet, do you mean _directly_ with the two ends of one usual Ethernet cable plugged into each device? In that case you probably need to use a [crossover cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable)

Comment: 169.254.x.x addresses mean that your RasPi is still looking for a real IP address from a DHCP server.

Answer (score 6):

You could find the IP address using `arp-scan` or `nmap`'s ping scan), but could also use the default `/etc/hostname` *alarmpi* in place of the IP address if DNS is working in your network.

If your DNS is not working, then do

`nmap -T5 -sP 192.168.0.0-255` replacing the network id part of the address accordingly.

OR

`arp-scan --localnet`

to get a list of IP addresses using the IP address of the currently active network device: Results will be IPs that share the same network (subnet).

After that, read the Raspberry Pi Installation Guide at the bottom.
e.g. https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-3.
It is only tricky in that it fails to mention that you cannot login as root on a headless Pi.

## SSH Login

Root login is disabled by default so you need to use the default Arch Linux ARM user/password, see [Where does the word "alarm" come from?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345385/what-does-the-al-in-alarm-the-default-arch-linux-arm-processor-usernamepas):

Existing non-root username: **alarm**

Associated Password: **alarm**

Therefore, in your example you'd want to type `ssh alarm@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` or just `ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`. Fill in the `x`s with the IP address of your Raspberry Pi.

Once you are logged in, you can switch to the root user:
`login` or as an su subprocess `su -l root`, in both cases the password is **root**.

Answer (score 3):

Try to connect with "root", because I think "alarmpi" is not a valid user (it is the default host name). It is written on the Archlinux Raspberry's download page: "Default login   Username: root Password: root"

Comment: I have still not managed to connect... Maybe I will wait for the keyboard and check if something else is wrong then.

Comment: Are you sure you have to connect to the port 22, and not another one ?

Comment: Since OpenSSH version 7, the default value of `#PermitRootLogin` in `sshd_config` has changed from "yes" to "prohibit-password". Thus, you cannot login as `root` with newer versions. https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.0 ... use `alarm` user and password `alarm` for first time boot

Comment: Cannot be the answer. It is a connection problem, not login problem. The OP did not even connect to the SSH port.

Answer (score 2):

This may not a solution for your this could be find a way out.

> A. Ping your raspberry pi from OSX.
>
> > If it is reachable check the sshd is running or not (you can do a port scan).
> > If it is not reachable check the raspberry ip address, I have mentioned below.
>
> B. check whether the user is granted for ssh or not.
>
> > if not add it.
>
> C. Check the IP address of the two devices.
>
> > If your OSX have a class C ip then PI should be class C ip ie. 192.168.1.3 and should be in same subnet.

**Probable solution**

I think this address 169.254.233.8 may cause the problem.

1. set your OSX ip address like 192.168.1.2
2. change your raspberry ip to 192.168.1.3
3. connect to pi using ssh alarmpi@192.168.1.3

I think this may helpful.

Thank you
Shantanu Banerjee

Comment: Given the problem stems from not having a keyboard on his Pi, and cannot connect over SSH, this may be a tad tricky :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, SSH is not enabled by default. you need to enable it first

```
sudo mv /boot/boot_enable_ssh.rc /boot/boot.rc
```

without a keyboard, you can use Ubuntu live cd and boot from it. then put SD in and do the mv in Ubuntu

regarding IP, you can install BIND on your mac. this way Pi will get an IP. Private IP would not work.

Comment: This is stated [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Advanced_Setup#Setting_up_for_remote_access_.2F_headless_operation), following the statement _These instructions assume you're using the official **Debian distro** for the Pi_ (emphasis mine)

Comment: On Arch|ARM ssh is enabled by default. Example here: https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv6/raspberry-pi

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem the default user in archlinux is not "alarmpi" nor "pi" but "root" with the password "root".

The ssh-server `sshd` is started automatically but the user "pi" is only used in raspbian.

Comment: Hey there, my answer conflicts with yours from my recent experience. Perhaps "root" over ssh has been disabled since Apr 21, 2015?

Comment: Since OpenSSH version 7, the default value of `#PermitRootLogin` in `sshd_config` has changed from "yes" to "prohibit-password". Thus, you cannot login as `root` with newer versions. https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.0 ... use `alarm` user and password `alarm` for first time boot

Answer (score 0):

It may have something about your ssh-key.

I have the same problem, even i format my sd card and "dd" my system again, i can't connect to my raspberry pi via ssh.

So i try to connect with out user name.

It tells me that "WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!".

I cleaned my old host via "ssh-keygen -f "/home/XXXX/.ssh/known_hosts" -R X.X.X.X"
It comes well after i do this.

May it can help you.

Answer (score -1):

I could not get this to work until I created a new use with sudo privlages

Comment: And how would the OP go about doing this?