# Configuring ethernet connection

Tags: networking, ethernet-port

I need to connect to my university network which is a bit tricky doing on the Raspberry Pi. 
I cannot find how to complete the manual set up steps described on [uni site](https://footprints.york.ac.uk/MRcgi/MRTicketPage.pl?USER=&MRP=0&MAJOR_MODE=DETAILS&MAXMININC=&MRNUMBERLIST=&LASTID=30723&ABN=&GRPDETAIL=&HISTORYKEY=&CUSTM=&MR=32624&PROJECTID=1), and the app that configures network automatically isn't working. 
The script looks for CPU architecture and compares it with the following: x86 (i386, i686, i486, i586) and x86_64. Although in Raspberry Pi case it returns error as processor type is arw61.

If you know a way to follow the steps described on manual set-up, or how i should execute the script, please let me know.

I am using raspbian-wheezy although I don't mind switching if that gets me online.

Following is the settings script:

```
#!/bin/sh

download_x86()
{
    wget --output-document="/tmp/XpressConnect-x86.tar.bz2" http://autoconnect.york.ac.uk//tools/XpressConnect-x86.tar.bz2
}

download_x64()
{
    wget --output-document="/tmp/XpressConnect-x64.tar.bz2" http://autoconnect.york.ac.uk//tools/XpressConnect-x64.tar.bz2
}

export HW_TYPE=`uname -m`

if [ "$HW_TYPE" = "i686" ] || [ "$HW_TYPE" = "i386" ] || [ "$HW_TYPE" = "i486" ] || [ "$HW_TYPE" = "i586" ]
then
    if [ -f "cabs/XpressConnect-x86.tar.bz2" ]
    then
    echo "Running x86 version..."
    export MY_DIR="`pwd`"
    cd /tmp
    tar xvjf "$MY_DIR/cabs/XpressConnect-x86.tar.bz2"
    "./XpressConnect-x86"
    else
      if [ -f "/tmp/cabs/XpressConnect-x86.tar.bz2" ]
      then
      echo "Running x86 version from /tmp..."
      cd /tmp
      tar xvjf "/tmp/cabs/XpressConnect-x86.tar.bz2"
          rm -f "/tmp/cabs/XpressConnect-x86.tar.bz2"
      "./XpressConnect-x86"
      else
      echo "Will download x86 version..."
      download_x86
      if [ "0" = "$?" ]
      then
              cd /tmp
          tar xvjf "XpressConnect-x86.tar.bz2"
          "./XpressConnect-x86"
      else
          echo "Unable to download the x86 version.   Please check your network connection" > /tmp/ubrun
          echo "and verify it is working properly!" >> /tmp/ubrun
          echo "(URL : http://autoconnect.york.ac.uk//tools/XpressConnect-x86.tar.bz2)" >> /tmp/ubrun
          echo "" >> /tmp/ubrun
          uname -a >> /tmp/ubrun
          xmessage -file /tmp/ubrun
          rm /tmp/ubrun
      fi
      fi
    fi
else 
     if [ "$HW_TYPE" = "x86_64" ]
     then
     if [ -f "cabs/XpressConnect-x64.tar.bz2" ]
     then
         echo "Running x64 version..."
         export MY_DIR="`pwd`"
         cd /tmp
         tar xvjf "$MY_DIR/cabs/XpressConnect-x64.tar.bz2"
         "./XpressConnect-x64"
       else
       if [ -f "/tmp/cabs/XpressConnect-x64.tar.bz2" ]
       then
           echo "Running x64 version from /tmp..."
           cd /tmp
           tar xvjf "/tmp/cabs/XpressConnect-x64.tar.bz2"
               rm -f "/tmp/cabs/XpressConnect-x64.tar.bz2"
           "./XpressConnect-x64"
       else
           echo "Will download x64 version..."
           download_x64

           if [ "0" = "$?" ];
           then
           cd /tmp
           tar xvjf "XpressConnect-x64.tar.bz2"
           "/tmp/XpressConnect-x64"
           else
           echo "Unable to download the x64 version.   Please check your network connection" > /tmp/ubrun
           echo "and verify it is working properly!" >> /tmp/ubrun
           echo "(URL : http://autoconnect.york.ac.uk//tools/XpressConnect-x64.tar.bz2)" >> /tmp/ubrun
           echo "" >> /tmp/ubrun
           uname -a >> /tmp/ubrun
           xmessage -file /tmp/ubrun
           rm /tmp/ubrun
           fi
           fi
     fi
     else
    echo "Unable to determine the type of processor in this machine.  Reported type was " $HW_TYPE "."
    xmessage "Unable to determine the type of processor in this machine. Reported type was " $HW_TYPE "."
     fi
fi
```

Comment: This script only figures out what processor type you have got and installs appropriate connection application. From the description you just need to open TLS tunnel between your university and Pi. Probably here: http://unvexed.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-set-up-real-encrypted-vpn.html or here: http://wiki.debian.org/OpenVPN could be some useful information.

Comment: So did you fix [your SSH problem](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/3525/3763) (in which case you should accept or post an answer) or do you use a keyboard now?

Comment: I use Keyboard but I will be testing SSH soon